# Why do I get a yellow “0 flag” alert on the top bar?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Why do I get a yellow “0 flag” alert on the top bar, on Academia, where I am not a moderator? It links to the “tools” page, where there is nothing for me to do:

[image]

Same situation exists on Meta:

[image]

It's weird to get an alert for “0 flags”, especially on a site where I am not moderator anyway… And it's stable, it's not a transient issue, it's been that way for a few minutes.

Comment: It's weird, it does not show up in the mod view.

Comment: I've seen that one before, intermittently, when one of *my own* posts had pending suggested edits, and then the circle went down from 1 to 0 after I took care of the suggested edit, but it did remain a little after.

Comment: @gerrit eykanal confirmed that there was no flag (on my own posts or any other) on the site at that point in time…

Comment: @F'x it happen to me also ... It went away eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, [this was my bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189872/3) - fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This might very well be just a glitch in the system—if there are no messages to be moderated, then nothing should be displayed!

However, as someone with over 20k reputation, you have access to all the same tools as moderators do, but perhaps without "diamond" privileges.

Comment: I didn't think privileges on Academia.SE [went higher than 4000.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) (and maybe that's true for Betas in general?)

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a +1 symbol exactly the same way  -when I click on it, there is a link to a "1 x not an answer", when I click on that - nothing.

Edit: wait a second, I think that was the one I mistakenly did this morning.